# Geeky stuff - как это по-русски?

Tags: software, it

Geeky stuff - как бы вы перевели это выражение на русский?

Поясняю. Это рубрика для статей о том как использовать то, чем обычно пользуются IT-шники (программисты, сисадмины и т.п. "geeks") для людей других профессий. Пример: "Git для переводчиков".

Это не обязательно должен быть буквальный перевод.

Comment: "Geeky stuff" само по себе не кажется мне хорошим названием для такой рубрики, почему бы не назвать её как есть: "IT-инструменты для непрофессионалов".

Comment: *Айтишники — людям*

Comment: Are you asking specifically about how to convey the phrase "geeky stuff" in Russian or looking for an advice on naming your article? The latter is opinion based and is not quite fit for this site. If you are looking for the former, could you please expand your question a little bit? Say, provide a sentence in Russian with a gap to fill. Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi: there are no "gaps" to fill, it is supposed to be a category on a website. But I like your suggestion. Perhaps _Айтишные штучки_?

Comment: @badbishop: the thing with Stack Exchange is that we try to focus on questions which can be answered more or less objectively, with references, examples and such. "How do I convey this concept in Russian" is a good question for this site, "how do I name this category on a website" is not. The latter is a valid and interesting question, it's just not a good fit for us. You might want to focus on conveying "geeky stuff" in Russian, otherwise there's a good chance your question is closed as off-topic. The best way to ask this is come up with a sentence which has a gap to fill. Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi Айтишники - тоже люди)) Sorry, could not resist.

Answer (score 2):

Если это рубрика на сайте, то думается, что подходящее название:
Чемоданчик гика

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю несколько вариантов:

- Гиковские штучки
- От гиков
- IT-инструменты
- Айтишные штучки
- IT для всех

Comment: Можно ещё «Гиковщина».

Comment: это гиковская тема

Comment: Гиковский арсенал

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что нужно в этом названии обойтись без слов «гик», «айтишник», потому что целевая аудитория с этими словами не знакома.

Поскольку компьютеры уже являются неотъемлемой частью нашей жизни, необязательно подчеркивать «компьютерность» этого раздела.

Теперь посмотрим на пример: "Git для переводчиков". Что тут имеется в виду? Нестандартное использвание инструмента для работы. Вот в эту сторону было бы неплохо подумать.

«Штучки» — хорошее слово, хорошо передает смысл stuff. Еще есть более официальное «Решения». Попробуем:

1. Профессиональные решения
2. Решения экспертов
3. Советы бывалых
4. Хитрые решения
5. Тех. рецепты / Тех. советы